# How do I create a directory inside of the documents folder?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Here was my attempt at finding the document folder that is in any user and then creating a folder. I'm relatively new to c++ and just trying to figure out how directories work

```
  void useraccess::createtxt() {
    //name is a pre-defined string
    cout << "Creating user\n";

    #ifdef _WIN32
    LPTSTR path = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, 0, NULL, &path);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        path + \\name;
        CreateDirectoryA(path, NULL);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error finding documents folder";
    }

    #elif __APPLE__

    #else
        cout << "Error";
    #endif
}
```

Comment: I know that is not how you are suppose to add things to LPTSTR but i just wanted to show what I was aiming for.

Comment: Your problem here is not figuring out "how directories work", but figuring out how C++ works. `path + \\name;` is not valid C++. You obviously want to concatenate something to a string. If you were to open a C++ book, and search through for the right chapter, I'm sure that your C++ book will have plenty of examples of doing that. If you don't know how something is done in C++, that's what you do: read about it in your book. Trying random things that you think might be valid C++ code, crossing you fingers, and hoping that it works, does not have very good chances of succeeding.

Comment: You love to follow me around to tell me to open a book LOL. I'm trying to learn off of youtube tutorials and stackoverflow questions. So i'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough when I commented above saying that I know that it wasn't the correct way. That is why i asked the question in the first place.

Comment: "I'm trying to learn off of youtube tutorials and stackoverflow questions." Get. A. Book. The typical utube video about C++ is made by a n00b. You'll learn bs.

Comment: Since you are a "new contributor", it is logically impossible for me to "follow you around". And to reiterate, it's true that you will never learn C++ from some random youtube videos and stackoverflow.com questions. I'd like to think that I know C++ fairly well. And I learned it before Youtube or stackoverflow.com ever existed, and even if they existed back then, that's not how I would've gone about learning C++, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj_core.h>


int main()
{
    PWSTR path_temp;

    if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_PublicDocuments, 0, nullptr, &path_temp) != S_OK) {
        std::cerr << "SHGetKnownFolderPath() failed :(\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::wstring path{ path_temp };
    CoTaskMemFree(path_temp);

    path += L"\\foobar";

    if (SHCreateDirectory(nullptr, path.c_str()) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        std::cerr << "SHCreateDirectory() failed :(\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::wcout << L"Directory \"" << path << L"\" created.\n\n";
}
```

Comment: The `std::wstring` c'tor can throw, leaking the memory reference through `path_temp`. The solution is to pass `path_temp` into a `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter.